# Do you know any online tool that creates ASCII Tables for proper use on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, markdown, tables

There is one I know at http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html that takes a TAB delimited input and formats as Ascii Table.

But do you know other such online tools, that take more input types like CSV.

Comment: While this question is asked in the context of Stack Overflow, it's really just asking for a list of utilities.

Comment: @Tim awww. It's still fairly relevant to SO. Voting to reopen

Comment: I agree with Tim. How about migrating to Web Apps?

Comment: @pop duplicate http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables

Answer (score 2):

Obtain your CSV data, I will use this as an example:

```
"id","category","name","icon","field 4","field 5","field 6","field 7","field 8","field 9","description"
"1","1","Currency Token Test Token 4","INV_Misc_Coin_09","0","1","0","0","0","2","Text that describes this item can be found here."
"2","1","Currency Token Test Token 2","ability_cheapshot","0","1","2","0","0","1",""
"4","1","Currency Token Test Token 5","INV_Misc_Coin_07","0","4","3","0","0","1",""
"22","41","Birmingham Test Item 3","INV-Sword_53","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"42","1","Badge of Justice","Spell_Holy_ChampionsBond","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"61","1","Dalaran Jewelcrafter's Token","INV_Misc_Gem_Variety_01","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"81","1","Dalaran Cooking Award","INV_Misc_Ribbon_01","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"101","22","Emblem of Heroism","Spell_Holy_ProclaimChampion","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"102","22","Emblem of Valor","Spell_Holy_ProclaimChampion_02","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
"103","2","Arena Points","Spell_Holy_ChampionsBond","0","0","0","0","0","0",""
```

---

2. Paste it in Wordpad.
3. Search for `"`, replace with empty string.
4. Search for `,`, replace with `<tab>`.
5. Paste it in the tool you linked
6. ```
   ╔═════╦══════════╦══════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║ id  ║ category ║             name             ║              icon              ║ field 4 ║ field 5 ║ field 6 ║ field 7 ║ field 8 ║ field 9 ║                   description                    ║
   ╠═════╬══════════╬══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
   ║   1 ║        1 ║ Currency Token Test Token 4  ║ INV_Misc_Coin_09               ║       0 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       2 ║ Text that describes this item can be found here. ║
   ║   2 ║        1 ║ Currency Token Test Token 2  ║ ability_cheapshot              ║       0 ║       1 ║       2 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║                                                  ║
   ║   4 ║        1 ║ Currency Token Test Token 5  ║ INV_Misc_Coin_07               ║       0 ║       4 ║       3 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║                                                  ║
   ║  22 ║       41 ║ Birmingham Test Item 3       ║ INV-Sword_53                   ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║  42 ║        1 ║ Badge of Justice             ║ Spell_Holy_ChampionsBond       ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║  61 ║        1 ║ Dalaran Jewelcrafter's Token ║ INV_Misc_Gem_Variety_01        ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║  81 ║        1 ║ Dalaran Cooking Award        ║ INV_Misc_Ribbon_01             ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║ 101 ║       22 ║ Emblem of Heroism            ║ Spell_Holy_ProclaimChampion    ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║ 102 ║       22 ║ Emblem of Valor              ║ Spell_Holy_ProclaimChampion_02 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ║ 103 ║        2 ║ Arena Points                 ║ Spell_Holy_ChampionsBond       ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║                                                  ║
   ╚═════╩══════════╩══════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
   ```

Comment: I do not consider this useful, as it involves too much steps. And what if you don't have access to such tool. I post many answers from a mobile device.

Comment: very cool but not the web app the OP asked for..

Comment: Cut and paste the CSV in the following online tool http://ascii.gallery/table and it will generate the ascii table.